# Android How to stop animateTo in MapController

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

In order to animate to some point on map i use

> myMapController.animateTo(point);

But sometimes I have to run another animation to point. In order not to have some elements flashing I need to stop last animation.

I tried this two:

> myMapController.stopPanning()
>
> myMapController.stopAnimation(false);

but it didn't help

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop animation you need to call the method bellow with parameter `true` (not `false` as in your question):

```
myMapController.stopAnimation(true);
```

This stops the animation and moves map instantanely to the final location requested by `animateTo()`.

If you want to stop animation and keep the map in the position where it was (in the midle of animation), use the following:

```
    GeoPoint movingCenter = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(mapView.getWidth()/2, mapView.getHeight()/2);
    myMapController.stopAnimation(true);
    myMapController.setCenter(movingCenter);
```

Regards.